# Best way to distribute a Windows image for a small company

Tags: windows

We're a startup software company and all our developers have MSDN premium licenses. I'd like to have a windows 8 image on hand that has all our tools (Sql Server, Visual Studio, IIS configs etc) all ready to go. 
We operate our product on Azure and don't have a sys admin in house as we only need to look after a few developer machines.
I'm looking for some advice on which tools I need to be able to construct this image and how to deploy it. 
I'm more than happy to do some reading, but I don't know what tools to look for or how to get started. A quick list of what tools / options would be a massive help.

Comment: [Microsoft's own tools?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/solutionaccelerators/dd407791.aspx)

Comment: If you have a windows server license, you have everything you need.

Comment: Sounds like you want to become a sysadmin in a hurry. This isn't as close to picking up a new language as it is to starting over at Hello World. At this point this is really both a request for a product recommendation and overly broad. Consider TomTom's answer, and also consider hiring a sysadmin.

Answer (score 2):

Free altrernative as not paying additional money?

Helps to know what you do - seriously. You basically ask whether a car has some lights.

Windows - for a LOOONG time comes with install technologies and IIRC since 2008 those are image based. WDS (Windows Deployment Service).

So, you make a master install, pull an image from that, then can install that. THAT SAID: I would as developer refuse to use such an image - there are tricky things installing develoepr tools at times, and I want to make sure any issue I have is my own fault.

I suggest you hire an admin - note that this is a "vote to close" form me because users and beginner questions are not welcome here as per specifications set up by the owners of the site , check the FAQ. You are supposed to know your tools at least vagueley when you come here.